# Some help dealing with inject/unject and vector types

Tags: coq

I'm reading through CPDT while doing the readings and exercises from Pierce's course here: [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/670Fall12/](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/courses/670Fall12/)

This question relates to HW10 here: [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/670Fall12/HW10.v](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/courses/670Fall12/HW10.v)

Here's the code up to my question

```
Require Import Arith Bool List.
Require Import CpdtTactics MoreSpecif.

Set Implicit Arguments.


(* Length-Indexed Lists *)

Section ilist.
  Variable A : Set.

  Inductive ilist : nat -> Set :=
  | Nil : ilist O
  | Cons : forall n, A -> ilist n -> ilist (S n).

  Definition ilength n (l : ilist n) := n.

  Fixpoint app n1 (ls1 : ilist n1) 
               n2 (ls2 : ilist n2) 
           : ilist (n1 + n2) :=
    match ls1 
      (*in (ilist n1) return (ilist (n1 + n2))*)
    with
      | Nil => ls2
      | Cons _ x ls1' => Cons x (app ls1' ls2)
    end.

  (* Coq automatically adds annotations to the 
     definition of app. *)
  Print app.


  Fixpoint inject (ls : list A) : ilist (length ls) :=
    match ls with
      | nil => Nil
      | h :: t => Cons h (inject t)
    end.
  Print inject.

  Fixpoint unject n (ls : ilist n) : list A :=
    match ls with
      | Nil => nil
      | Cons _ h t => h :: unject t
    end.

  Theorem inject_inverse : forall ls, 
          unject (inject ls) = ls.
    induction ls; crush.
  Qed.


  (* Exercise (20 min) : Prove the opposite, that inject (unject ls) = ls.
     You cannot state this theorem directly, since ls : ilist n
     and inject (unject ls) : ilist (length (unject ls)). 
     One approach is to define an alternative version of equality ilist_eq 
     on ilists and prove that the equality holds under this definition.
     If you do this, prove that ilist_eq is an equivalence relation (and try
     to automate the proof).

     Another more involved approach is to prove that n = length (unject ls) 
     and then to define a function that, given (ls : ilist n) and a 
     proof that m = n, produces an ilist m. In this approach you may 
     find proof irrelevance convenient. 
  *)
```

Because I really want to better understand dependent types and how to use proofs in programs, I decided to try to do the latter. Here is what I have so far.

```
Definition ilists_sizechange (n1 n2:nat) (l1:ilist n1) (P:n1=n2): ilist n2.
subst.
assumption.
Defined.

Lemma ilists_size_equal: forall n (ls:ilist n), n = length (unject ls).
Proof.
intros.
induction ls.
reflexivity.
simpl.
auto.
Qed.

Theorem unject_inject_thehardway: forall n (ls:ilist n),
  inject (unject ls) = ilists_sizechange ls (ilists_size_equal ls).
Proof.
intros.
induction ls.
simpl.
?????????????????
Qed.
```

When I get to "?????????????????" that's where I'm stuck. I have a target like `Nil = ilists_sizechange Nil (ilists_size_equal Nil)` and I'm not really sure what I can do here.

I tried writing `ilists_sizechange` as a more direct function, but failed to do so. Not sure how to massage the type checking.

I guess I'm curious first if this approach is fruitful, or if I'm making some fundamental mistake. I'm also curious what the most concise way of expressing `inject (unject ls) = ilists_sizechange ls (ilists_size_equal ls).` is...here there are two custom functions (the sizechange and the proof of equality), and one imagines it should be possible with just one.

Coq is great but the syntax around dependently types stuff can be tricky. I appreciate any help!

Edit: I realize that an inductive type or something expressing equality of two lists and then building up and showing the sizes are equal is probably easier (eg the first suggestion they have), but I want to understand this case because I can imagine running into these sorts of issues in the future and I want to know how to work around them.

Edit2: I was able to make it past the Nil case using the following

```
dep_destruct (ilists_size_equal Nil).
compute.
reflexivity.
```

But then get stuck on the Cons case...I will try to prove some theorems and see if I can't get there, but I think I'm still missing something conceptual here.

Comment: "Exercise (20 min)" is a very funny estimation.

Answer (score 3):

Although functions may depend on proof objects, one approach (I'm going to show below) is to define the functions so that they don't use the proof objects except to construct other proof objects and to eliminate absurd cases, ensuring that opaque proofs never block computation. Another approach is to fully embrace dependently typed programming and the unification of "proofs as programs", but that's a much bigger paradigm shift to explain, so I'm not going to do that.

Starting with `ilists_sizechange`, we now care about the shape of the term constructed by tactics, so not all tactics are allowed. Not wanting to use the equality proof rules out the tactic `subst`. Instead we can recurse (`induction`) on the list `l1` and pattern-match (`destruct`) on the natural number `n2`; there are four cases:

- two absurd ones, which can be eliminated by using the equality (`discriminate`)
- the `0 = 0` case, where you can just construct the empty list
- the `S m1 = S m2` case, where you can construct `Cons`, use the induction hypothesis (i.e., recursive call), and then you are asked for a proof of `m1 = m2`, which is where you can fall back to regular reasoning without caring what the proof term looks like.

```
Definition ilists_sizechange (n1 n2:nat) (l1:ilist n1) (P:n1=n2): ilist n2.
Proof.
  revert n2 P. (* Generalize the induction hypothesis. *)
  induction l1; destruct n2; discriminate + constructor; auto.
Defined.
```

While the rest of the proof below would technically work with that definition, it is still not ideal because any computation would unfold `ilist_sizechange` into an ugly function. While we've been careful to give that function the "right" computational behavior, tactic-based programming tends to be sloppy about some finer details of the syntax of those functions, which makes later proofs where they appear hard to read.

To have it look nicer in proofs, one way is to define a `Fixpoint` with the `refine` tactic. You write down the body of the function in Gallina, and put underscores for the proof terms, which become obligations that you have to prove separately. `refine` is not the only way to perform this technique, there's also the `Program Fixpoint` command and the Equations plugin. I would recommend looking into Equations. I stick with `refine` out of familiarity.

As you can see, intuitively all this function does is deconstruct the list `l1`, indexed by `n1`, and reconstruct it with index `n2`.

```
Fixpoint ilists_sizechange (n1 n2 :nat) (l1:ilist n1) {struct l1} : n1 = n2 -> ilist n2.
Proof.
  refine (
    match l1, n2 with
    | Nil, 0 => fun _ => Nil
    | Cons x xs, S n2' => fun EQ => Cons x (ilists_sizechange _ _ xs _)
    | _, _ => fun _ => _
    end
  ); try discriminate.
  auto.
Defined.
```

The proof of `ilists_size_equal` needs no modification.

```
Lemma ilists_size_equal: forall n (ls:ilist n), n = length (unject ls).
Proof.
intros.
induction ls.
reflexivity.
simpl.
auto.
Qed.
```

For the final proof, there is one more step: first generalize the equality proof.
The idea is that `ilists_sizechange` doesn't actually look at it, but when it makes a recursive call it will need to construct some other proof, and this generalization allows you to use the induction hypothesis independently of that particular proof.

```
Theorem unject_inject_ : forall n (ls:ilist n) (EQ : n = length (unject ls)),
  inject (unject ls) = ilists_sizechange ls EQ.
Proof.
intros n ls; induction ls; cbn.
- reflexivity.
- intros EQ. f_equal. apply IHls. (* Here we have ilists_sizechange applied to some big proof object, which we can ignore because the induction hypothesis generalizes over all such proof objects *)
Qed.
```

Then you want to specialize that theorem to use a concrete proof, ensuring that such a proof exists so the theorem is not vacuous.

```
Theorem unject_inject : forall n (ls:ilist n),
  inject (unject ls) = ilists_sizechange ls (ilists_size_equal _).
Proof.
  intros; apply unject_inject_.
Qed.
```

Comment: So how long do you estimate it took for you to solve this one?

Comment: As a regular user of dependent types, it's a trivial exercise (though teaching the solution is more interesting). However I believe it's possible to be proficient in Coq without ever requiring a mental model of dependent types (by viewing the programming language Gallina as entirely separate from the proof language Ltac), in which case these puzzles could take an unbounded amount of time.

Comment: Over the last 6 years, I have been trying to teach Coq without dependent types to get a lower entry barrier, and the problem you are mentioning shows up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

```
(* Length-Indexed Lists *)
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Section ilist.
  Variable A : Set.

  Inductive ilist : nat -> Set :=
  | Nil : ilist O
  | Cons : forall {n}, A -> ilist n -> ilist (S n).

  Fixpoint inject (ls : list A) : ilist (length ls) :=
    match ls with
      | nil => Nil
      | h :: t => Cons h (inject t)
    end.

  Fixpoint unject {n} (ls : ilist n) : list A :=
    match ls with
      | Nil => nil
      | Cons h t => h :: unject t
    end.

  Definition cast {A B : Set} (e : A = B) : A -> B :=
    match e with eq_refl => fun x => x end.

  Fixpoint length_unject n (l : ilist n) : length (unject l) = n :=
    match l with
    | Nil => eq_refl
    | Cons _ l => f_equal S (length_unject _ l)
    end.

  Theorem unject_inverse n (ls : ilist n) :
    cast (f_equal ilist (length_unject _ ls)) (inject (unject ls)) = ls.
  Proof.
    induction ls as [|n x l IH]; simpl; trivial.
    revert IH.
    generalize (inject (unject l)).
    generalize (length_unject _ l).
    generalize (length (unject l)).
    intros m e.
    destruct e.
    simpl.
    intros; congruence.
  Qed.

End ilist.
```

The trick is to make your goal sufficiently general, and then to destruct the equality. The generalization is required to ensure that your goal is well-typed after destructing; failing to generalize will often lead to dependent-type errors.

Here, I've defined the length lemma by hand to be able to use the reduction machinery. But you could also have used proof irrelevance to get the proof to reduce to `eq_refl` after the fact.

Comment: Thank you! This answer plus Li-yao's are very helpful. In particular the length_unject function as you defined it here is very interesting.